# Iterate using particular dll name

Tags: batch-file, dll

Is it possible to iterate a folder searching for particular dlls name using batch file? I know that *.dll iterates all the dll in specified location. But I couldn't find solution for searching for particular dlls using batch file. My dll naming structure will be like myassembly.{name}.dll. I have to search for the dlls in the name starting with myassembly.

I have tried as myassembly.*.dll. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the where command:

```dos
Where folder:myassembly.*.dll
```

This searches your directory, *named folder*, for all dll's whose name begin with myassembly.

```dos
Where/R folder myassembly.*.dll
```

This searches your directory, *named folder*, and all of it's sub directories for all dll's whose name begin with myassembly.

Type **where/?** and hit enter in a cmd window for more information.

**[Edit /]**

Based on your comment, you are probably wanting something like this

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where %id%:myassembly.*.dll') Do Echo=%%~fA
```

Comment: for /f %%f in ('dir /b %id%\myassembly.*.dll') do echo %id%\%%f    This is the command I have used to iterate the folders. I'm not clear where to add the where command. Can you edit in my command?

Comment: In my above command %id% contains the folder path

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer